# MySql Delete - same like select ( join )

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I copied some records from one table to another
with this query :

```
insert into pages_finished (keyword,pages,resultlist,done,current)
select keyword,pages,resultlist,done,current 
 from pages_done o  
 where  (select count(*) as totalPages from pages_done x  where x.keyword = o.keyword)-1 = pages
```

Now I want to delete the same records from the source table,
I was thinking it would be simple as:

```
delete from pages_done o  
 where  (select count(*) as totalPages from pages_done x  where x.keyword = o.keyword)-1 = pages
```

but that doesn't work.
Could anyone tell me what is the right way to do that?

After @bgdrl answer, I'm thinking about running only the select,
get the id's of all records that should be copied,
and then delete;
but I think there must be an easier solution, anyone?

Even though  marked @bgdrl answer as the right answer,
it is only because of that  a fact.

To anyone interested with what I ended up doing :
I did the same select I started with (but selected only the id column, since selecting all the columns would have killed my poor computer),
exported it to an `INSERT STATMENTS` (using mysqlworkbench),
opened the text file in notepad,
replaced all the `INSERT INTO`... with `DELETE FROM WHERE ID=`,
and run that query in mysql.

I feel so stupid using this way, but had no other choice apparently.

Comment: why didn't u handle this with  mysql `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: @diEcho because `LAST_INSERT_ID()` only returns a single value, whilst the INSERT statement could insert many rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PLEASE BACKUP THE TABLE BEFORE FOLLOWING THE STEPS.**

Follow the following STEPS

**STEP 1**

```
CREATE TABLE pages_done_ids 
    SELECT o.id FROM pages_done AS o  
    WHERE 
    (
        SELECT count(*) AS totalPages 
        FROM pages_done AS x  
        WHERE x.keyword = o.keyword
    )-1 = o.pages
```

**STEP 2**

```
DELETE FROM pages_done AS o  
WHERE o.id IN (SELECT id FROM pages_done_ids)
```

**STEP 3**

```
DROP TABLE pages_done_ids;
```

OK, you may accomplish it with one transaction using [TEMPORARY TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

Happy Querying!

Comment: This looks like a great idea!

Comment: Check the SQL, just wrote it blindly.

Comment: with a little modification, this was what i needed :)
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From mysql site: "You cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. This applies to statements such as DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, UPDATE". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html

Comment: ok bgdrl, that is great to know, but i still need a solution.
does anyone have an idea how to approach this ?

Comment: why do you need this condition?  where x.keyword = o.keyword)-1 = pages. What are you trying to filter?

Comment: basicly it compares the total row count for the specific keyword and compares it to the pages column, which should match.
the -1 is because the rows contains also page number 0.